# check string format height x width python

Tags: python, regex, string, formatting

I have a csv file imported from python.

In this csv file there is a column where I need to check the string that contains dimensions height x width that could be intxint, floatxfloat eg.

12x12

123.45x123.45

sometimes there are even:

123x123mm

where the units are given. As I need to retrieve the values for height and width, I need to ensure that a string either nxn, or floatxfloat is valid (then I can split into array around 'x').

Is this possible with a regex, or would it be better to:

- remove the whitespace
- remove any letters in the string that are not 'x' (I am assuming the units are the same or height and width)
- perform a list split around 'x'
- check length of split list for two items that are float (or int) values

Would there be a better way to perform this?

Comment: Is this `' 123x123mm'` only an example and can there be other units, too or is `mm` the only possible unit which could be in there? And can the unit also be part of the first value or only of the second?

Comment: as so often - you should post a proper [mcve], with code what you do, what you want, an example what your input is and what kind of output you expect. Otherwise it's too much about guessing here. We even don't know in which context you want to parse this column: while importing with `pandas`' `read_csv`, while iterating over it simply by opening the file, do you use perhaps `csv` or are you trying with `numpy`'s `genfromtxt`.........?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex would be relatively simple.

```
import re

data = [ "12x12", "123.45x123.45", "123x123mm"] 

p = "^([\d.]+)x([\d.]+).*$"
for s in data:
    m = re.match(p, str(s))
    print("----------")
    print("m.groups() = ", m.groups())
    print("m.group(1) =", m.group(1))
    print("m.group(2) =", m.group(2))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
----------
m.groups() =  ('12', '12')
m.group(1) = 12
m.group(2) = 12
----------
m.groups() =  ('123.45', '123.45')
m.group(1) = 123.45
m.group(2) = 123.45
----------
m.groups() =  ('123', '123')
m.group(1) = 123
m.group(2) = 123
```

The regex pattern translates like this...

```
p = "^([\d.]+)x([\d.]+).*$"

^        = Match the start of string.
([\d.]+) = Match as group 1, any amount of digits (0-9) and periods (.) in any order  
x        = Match the actual string "x". This assumes all values with be separated by an "x"
([\d.]+) = Again, match as group 2, any amount of digits (0-9) and periods (.) in any order
.*       = Match any number of any character
 $       = Match end of string
```

If a match is successful, you will receive a regex match object, which will contain 2 groups. Group one will be the `height` and group two will be the `width`. Printing `m.groups()` gives you all the groups matched. You can access the individual values with `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)`.

Comment: Thank you. I have never been that great at getting regex correct, therefore am hesitant to use these sometimes!

Comment: Regex can be tough :) Find a good regex cheatsheet online.

Comment: I have added an extra .* between group 1 and x making the regex:
"^([\d.]+).*x([\d.]+).*$"
in case there is also 1234mmx1234mm

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps simply a combination of `split` and `strip`:

```
'  123x123 mm  '.strip(' m').split('x')
# ['123', '123']

'  123.45x123.1 mm  '.strip(' m').split('x')
# ['123.45', '123.1']
```

Comment: I do like the simplicity of your answer, but I might not always be 'mm'. Sorry for not making that clear! This is why I have gone for the other regex answer. Might be a bit overkill for what I need, but not to bothered about execution time here.